# Can religions like Islam or Hinduism be represented respectfully in a fictionalized/fantastical Earth?

Tags: magic, culture, religion

Assuming this fictionalized Earth possesses features common to post-Tolkien fantasy: monsters/cryptids, sorcery, intelligent humanoids, etc.

In the past, firebirds, djinni, spirits, angels, demons, basilisks, witchcraft, dragons, etc were generally accepted to be actualities of the world often reinforced by religious belief, and even now, people tend toward a belief in the preternatural where spirits, angels/demons, practical magic, chakras, etc are concerned.

In western liberal society, even though adherents to religions like Christianity, Judaism, Buddhism often voice opposition to how magic/fantasy elements and their faith are depicted in fiction (His Dark Materials comes to mind), it's generally not out of the question for Christian/Jewish characters to appear alongside monsters or demons or characters who practical sorcery. Conversely, in Islamic societies, genre fiction is often thought of as a force opposed to Quranic truth, and fiction featuring Hinduism is frequently ostensibly pro-Hinduism.

My understanding is that religious doctrine usually explicitly describes magic/witchcraft and spirits/demons as physical actualities within dogma, so it's blasphemous to depict those things as physical actualities outside of dogma, especially within the same universe as said religious doctrine. In other words, is it possible to respectfully write a culture that believes in the divinity of Trimurti or the Abrahamic God according to Islam in a world where wizards can perform feats otherwise only achievable through God, or in which elves are superior to humans, or does that concept seem antagonistic toward religious belief? If I can make the question a two-parter, where would elves, dwarves, orcs factor into a world where Christianity, Buddhism, Islam, Hinduism, and Judaism are major religions?

Comment: While this is a fantastic question to discuss in our chat, this isn't really an answerable question for the main site, and I get the feeling this will be closed as "too opinion-based". A lot of that has to do with the fact that there isn't one correct response to what you're asking, which is what this site looks for and promotes.

Comment: This would actually make a marvellous Writing SE question - it should probably be asked there

Comment: @Pingcode Thanks for the heads-up. I'm new to the site; just found the chat and writing sites

Comment: @Pleiades Thanks; I'll relocate to chat

Comment: Not a problem. Don't worry if it takes a while to learn your way around the network. Each site's a bit different and it can be confusing at first. You'll find everyone's more than willing to help out though. ^-^

Comment: Why not use a live religion as a base for a fictional one?

Comment: The basic problem you have is that we don't often act respectably in our society today, so it's hard to imagine how you would do so in fantasy fiction (which would almost always appear heretical if not outright blasphemous to the devout).  For every person you meet who agrees with you there is at least one person who will not - on any and every matter in the universe.  BTW, I agree with Pleides, the question (and literary idea) is excellent... but your readership will likely be small and detractors very, very vocal (not sure that should stop you, though).

Comment: Asked on Writing: https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/35036/1993

Answer (score 4):

No

No matter what you do, someone will be upset. You need to make your own religions or ignore the haters.

For the second part, it depends on which came first. Are the other races something that expressed from human stock like in [Shadowrun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowrun) or genetically engineered or have they always been there like in [Bright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bright_(film))?

If the religions came first, then they would be most likely anti new species because it doesn't fit their worldview

If the races have always been there, then chances would be they wouldn't care beyond racist fringe elements.

Comment: I figured as much.

On the subject of the other races, my thinking is that they'd be offshoots of homo sapiens that predate Abrahamic faith or Hinduism, so I suppose they'd be thought of as a subhuman minority as a matter of course.

Comment: How can you portray any of the Abrahamic religions in a positive light in a world with magic when their holy books say "Suffer a witch not to live"? They already killed enough and witches aren't real. Just imagine if witches were real?

Comment: @Thorne If witches were real, the sacred books of most religions would say "Thou shalt protect a witch to live", Slaying the powerful capable seems counterproductive. Any ruling class worth its salt would make sure magic users were on their side. Ultimately it's about consolidating power. Of course, if all witches were natural anarchists and born revolutionaries it would be different and witch hunts a national sport.

Comment: @a4android, if witches were real, the sacred books of most religions could still say "suffer a witch not to live".  It could be that the original text was referring to good/evil witches and the numerous translations then garbled this just to say "witch". For instance I recently read an article about a Christian bible quote that I cannot recall correctly, along the lines of "and the old man looked after the young girl" and the article said how the original Hebrew word used for "looked after" had a "in the married sense" context. there could be something Missing in Translation.

Comment: @EveryBitHelps I tend to suspect that *real* witches would become part of the power structures. So religions would tend to support them rather than persecute. Your point about translation is a good one. Mistranslations of the Bible are frequent. A lot of the original meaning is missing. Makes things confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I'll focus on the second part of the question.

Each religion has its own views on the birth of humanity and so they would have their own views on the existence of other races.

First and foremost, do these races have always been around or do they sprouted around at a specific time?

If they have always been around, then the religions will probably include them on the legends. (Everyone knows the parable of the Good elf...)

The Bible has giants, nephilins, and all kind of fantastical animals walking around so it wouldn't be much of a stretch to include dwarves and elves on it.

Depending in the time period your story is set it would be good to give a read about the Golden Age of Islam. (As someone that likes the history of medicine, the history of Ibn Sina is fantastic)

Jews have it easy, since they believe to be the "Chosen People" it would be pretty easy to simply say that god created all races.

Christians have it a bit harder if you want to keep the Bible as it is. But then, if your elven merchants have ships full of spice and gold you will find that pretty quickly they will find ways to include them on the scriptures.

Budhism is a whole other subject, since its not so concerned with the creation of the world they will not have much problem accepting the other races, but depending on the time period you could have some kinda of "Racial Ladder" of reencarnation, with say Dwarves on the lower leves (So much greed!) and Hobbits on the top.

As for writing a story, my advice is try to talk with people from those religion and ask them about it. Don't go for simple stereotypes and have an open mind.

I'm a Budhist myself, and I sure would love to see more of my religion being represented on books, preferably something that is not some wise monk meditating on some isolated place, ready to give advices to the white protagonist.

Answer (score 0):

I think Thorne is right. How about Greek and Norse or even Celtic? These have been portrayed in a lot of sci-fi and fantasy stories already. If you still would want to use any of the religions you mentioned, you may want to consult subject matter experts i.e, priest, rabbi, imams etc. so that you can determine facts, what you can write about and be more accurate about it.

Comment: At least if you use dead religions, nobody will get upset.

Comment: Problem is, not all dead religions are [dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenism_(religion)).